how to route 2 wiregurds over 2 connections at the same time (eth0/wlan0)
The setup I have:
wg0 should go over eth0 and wg0-client should go over wlan0 interface.
Wireguard and interfaces are connected without a problem, but what is happening is that traffic on wg0-client is somehow directed via eth0 instead of wlan0.
I think this is the main problem:
PostUp = ip route add `dig +short some.domain.com`/32 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table 1111
PostUp = ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp dport 1111 lookup 1111

If I use that, wg0-client connects, but cannot send the data. If I change this to:
PostUp = ip route add `dig +short some.domain.com`/32 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table 1111
PostUp = ip rule add from 0.0.0.0/32 ipproto udp dport 1111 lookup 1111

ping via wg0-client starts working, but it is using eth0 instead of wlan0.
What could I try more, to always direct traffic to some.domain.com and port 1111 via wlan0, since on that port other side of wireguard is listening to the traffic from wlan0?

why would you do like this? use a bridge and combine both connections

Does this answer your question? Two wireguards via eth0 and wlan0 at the same time. One interface doesn't work properly

@Zac67 that is my post. I closed it since I thought it is working, but it is using eth0 instead wlan0 - that is why it worked. So now at least I guess I know that this specific part of config is wrong.

@djdomi PC1 at location A is connected to internet via ethernet (eth0) via ISP1 and wifi (wlan0) via ISP2. ISP2 connection has CGNAT. PC2 is at location B with single eth0 connection. So, I basically created 2 wireguard tunnels from PC1 to PC2. One is much faster than the other. PC2 initiates connection to PC1 via ISP1, but PC1 needs to do this towards PC2 because of the CGNAT.

@MarkoKraljevic You didn't close it yet and it is very much a double post. Please include all relevant information in one question and do close the other one.
